# Regex to select and replace spaces inside double brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a script which is used to tidy up MediaWiki files prior to conversion to confluence mark-up, this particular scenario I'm needing to fix page links which in MediaWiki are something like this

```
[[this is a page]]
```

the problem being that the actual page link would be this_is_a_page, the universal wiki converter isn't smart enough to realise this when it converts to confluence mark-up so you end up with broken links.

I've been trying to create a regex as part of my python script (I've already stripped out html and some other tags like < gallery> etc., the following regex selects all the links in question:

```
'\[\[(.*?)\]\]'
```

I just cant find a programmatic way to select only the spaces inside the [[ ]] so I can substitute them out for underscores. I've attempted using matches with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below regex and replace the matched spaces with underscores.

```
\s(?=[^\[\]]*]])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gH7pG6/5)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = " [[this is a page]]    goo hghg"
>>> m = re.sub(r'\s(?=[^\[\]]*]])', "_", s)
>>> m
' [[this_is_a_page]]    goo hghg'
```

`\s(?=[^\[\]]*]]`, it would match the spaces only if it's followed by any character not of `[` or `]` zero or more times and  the two closing `]]` brackets.

Comment: That is brilliant, works a treat :) thank you very much. shall accept answer when able.

Comment: would it be possible to restrict the search if a binary | was picked up such as [[this is a page | page name]] ?? its used in mediawiki as a label.

Comment: The regex would need to work on both [[this is a page]] and [[this is a page | page name]] - but yes that is right for the latter :)

Comment: If you intended then ask it as another question. Some one may help you :-)

Comment: Maybe a little offtopic, but for single square brackets is it enough to just remove the last square bracket from the Regex: `\s(?=[^\[\]]*])`? It works for me but I'm not sure if further changes are necessary for some corner-case scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `re.sub` and lambda expression

```
>>> import re
>>> test = '[[this is a page]] bla bla [[this is another page]]'
>>> re.sub(r'\[\[.+?\]\]', lambda x:x.group().replace(" ","_"), test)
'[[this_is_a_page]] bla bla [[this_is_another_page]]'
```

Comment: +1 for lambda which makes things simpler, but -1 for greedy quantifier.